# Quasisplit forms of wonderful varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-groups, spherical-varieties

I will assume that $k$ is a characteristic $0$ non-archimedean field. A classical result of Tits [T] states that a quasisplit connected reductive group $G$ over $k$ is classified up to strict isogeny by its Tits index: the Galois action on the Dynkin diagram.

There is a conjecture of Luna [PL] — a $G$-wonderful variety $X$ is classified by its spherical systems, which is roughly speaking, the root datum for $G$, the spherical root datum for $X$, the set of colors for $X$ and some axioms among them.

I want to study the quasisplit forms for homogeneous wonderful varieties: For $k$ a characteristic $0$ field, $\overline{k}$ its algebraic closure, for $\overline{X}$ a $\overline{G}$-wonderful variety over $\overline{k}$, by a quasisplit form of $\overline{X}$, I mean a $G$-variety $X$ over $k$, with $X_{\overline{k}}\cong \overline{X}$ and $G_{\overline{k}}\cong \overline{G}$ with $G$ being quasisplit.

$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$Looking at the forms for rank one spherical varieties for split groups $\SO_{n+1}$, $\SO_{n}\backslash \SO_{n+1}$, $n\geq 3$, we find that we need to include the Galois action on the codimension 1 divisors associated with certain Borel orbits maximal rank, in the recent draft, [Ben-Zvi, Sakellarides, and Venkatesh - Relative Langlands duality](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Esakellar/BZSVpaperV1.pdf), definition 4.3.4, the arthurs call these Borel orbits colors of even sphere type.

Recently, a restricted root system for a spherical variety $X$ over a general char $0$ field is constructed in [KK], their construction for the restricted root system is, roughly speaking taking the root system for $X_{\overline{k}}$ over the algebraic closure under the natural restriction map between the characters of maximal torus $T$ and the characters of maximal split torus $A$. In particular, a maximal split torus $A_{k}(X)$ is defined and we will call its dimension the split rank of $X$.

Rank 1 wonderful varieties are classified by Akhiezer in [A].
Now I want to ask: is it true that the split rank one quasisplit forms of wonderful varieties are classified by the Galois action on the spherical systems together with the Galois action on the colors of even sphere type? To begin with, can one extend the work of [KK] to define a **restricted spherical systems** which also include the colors of even sphere type which are defined over $k$.

Note one obvious difficulty is that for a split rank one spherical variety $X$, over algebraic closure, it can have a very large rank, say greater than two.

References:

[A] D.N. Akhiezer, [Equivariant completions of homogeneous algebraic varieties by homogeneous divisors](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02329739).

[KK] Knop, F. and Krötz, B., [Reductive group actions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.01005).

[PL] Bravi, P. and Luna, D., [An introduction to wonderful varieties with many examples of type $\mathrm F_4$](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2010.01.025).

[T] Tits, J., Classification of algebraic semisimple groups. In [Algebraic Groups and Discontinuous Subgroups](https://doi.org/10.1090/pspum/009).